# Appending together a variable number of data frames

Tags: r, append, rbind

I have dataframes in the same format, that might have anywhere from 1-100 dataframes.  The names are 1_raw, 2_raw, 3_raw, etc.

First, I include all of them into a file name list:

```
df_ls<- ls(pattern="raw")
```

Secondly, I want to call df_ls to append all of them into one master data frame:

```
master_df<-do.call(rbind,df_ls)
```

However, this second step is giving an error: 
 "error in do.call(rbind, filenames) : second argument must be a list"

Does anyone have any idea how I should make this work?

Comment: You may try `do.call(rbind, mget(df_ls))` assuming that all the datasets have the same number of columns and have the same colnmes.  Better would be to read all the datasets directly in to a list. `files <- list.files(pattern='.txt'); do.call(rbind,lapply(files, function(x) read.table(x,header=TRUE, sep=''))`

Comment: I used the mget function and it worked beaultifully.  Thank you!